# How secure are Azure WebJobs?

Tags: security, azure, azure-webjobs

Can a user of my web application access the executable of my Azure WebJob by any means in order to steal code or any other such information in files that were deployed alongside with the WebJob?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Only the owner/contributors of the containing Web App have access to the files (the same people who can publish).